# When trying to run the hello android test app i get an error APPCRASH and the emulator will not open

Tags: android, eclipse

**here is the full error**
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: emulator.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4c79ab54
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16559
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ba9b21e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0005a6f0
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.11
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

**here is the full src .java code**

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     TextView tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Hello, Android");
     setContentView(tv);


     //setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
 }
```

i am running in eclipse gallileo  for the 2.0 sdk, though i have tried others

Answer (score 1):

Did you state an SDK Version in your Manifest?

Are you selecting 'Android Application' after pressing Run?

You did everything listed here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html 
when installing the SDK?

Comment: I don't think the version is the problem.  Mine works fine without that being specified.